# The graph of any function $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is a level set for some function $F: \mathbb R^{n+1} \to \mathbb R$

Tags: differential-geometry

> Show that the graph of any function $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is a level set for some function $F: \mathbb R^{n+1} \to \mathbb R$.

Attempt:

Define $F: \mathbb R^{n+1} \to \mathbb R$ as 
$F(x_1,...,x_{n+1})= c$ if  $x_{n+1}=f(x_1,...,x_n)$, and $F(x_1,...,x_{n+1})=b$ otherwise.

Is this correct?

Because now $F^{-1}(c)$ will be the graph of $f$. Hence the graph of $f$ is a level set for some function.

Comment: That, or $F(x_1,...,x_{n+1})=x_{n+1}-f(x_1,...,x_n)$.

Comment: See first word of first comment.

Comment: Okie,  thanks  :)

Comment: @Human Is $F$ supposed to be continuous or smooth?

Comment: No condition on $F$.

Comment: But can we do this if $F$ is supposed to be continuous or smooth?

Comment: If $f$ is continuous then you can find a smooth $F$ with the desired property. This is not quite so easy, though.